# Step scaling option disabled for ECS Fargate service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate, aws-auto-scaling

I'm trying to setup auto-scaling for an ECS Fargate Service based on SQS Queue depth.

The idea is to stay at 0 tasks until there are messages in the queue and then apply a step scaling policy to gradually increase the number of tasks using cloudwatch alarms.

I'm mostly following this article here - https://adamtuttle.codes/blog/2022/scaling-fargate-based-on-sqs-queue-depth/

The problem is that step scaling itself is disabled when I try to update my service.

[image]

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Does [switching back to the old UI](https://repost.aws/questions/QUOpsw2IU5SDK2LRmUg0r_jw/ecs-step-scaling-option-always-disabled-on-new-ui) work for you?

Comment: You might have to [configure it via the CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/create-step-scaling-policy-cli.html#create-step-scaling-policy) instead.

Comment: @DMalan The old UI option was the first thing I looked for but unfortunately, I don't seem to have that toggle.